# Change permission on file in /sys folder

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, backlight, file-permissions

I am trying to turn off the backlight on the soft keys (home, menu, back and search).

My phone is a HTC Evo 3D running Ice Cream Sandwich.  Before, I had Gingerbread installed and I could use "Screen Filter" app to turn the lights off. After the upgrade, "Screen Filter" no longer works.

On one forum it says that if you edit the file `max_brightness` in folder

`/sys/class/leds/button-backlight`

from `255` to `0` and then switch the screen off and on again then the key lights stay off.

However, the file is read-only.

I want to make the file writable. Do I need to root my phone to do this?

Comment: Can you post the explicit access bits? (I.e. do a 'ls -l /sys/class/leds/button-backlight'). Or has the location changed (i.e. are there other files in the directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your phone must be rooted because to access that file the `/system` needs to be mounted as write-able

Once you obtain root you can run this command inside a shell:
`su`
`chmod 777 /sys/class/leds/button-backlight/max_brightness`

Then just navigate to that file and edit it using a file browser. What the `chmod 777` command does is change the permissions on that file so that you can edit it. After you finish I would suggest changing the permissions back to what they were.

The original permissions were probably `0666`.
So it would be like this: `chmod 0666 /sys/class/leds/button-backlight/max_brightness`

To encompass t0mm13b's remark below, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371865/changing-some-system-file-values-in-android-failing) for information on how to make the file write-able at boot, instead of having a script be run at each boot that makes it write-able.

Comment: Are you sure this will work, as that sounds a temporary measure, ie. permissions will be lost upon reboot? BTW: OP's handset is not-rooted so not a good answer either!

Comment: That will work provided the handset is not rebooted, for a more permanent solution, the `init.rc` script would have to be modified and rebuilt within the ram-disk and for that the `boot.img` would have to be re-created.

Comment: Well obviously someone doesn't read answers fully. And not necessarily. A permanent solution can still be achieved without any need to dive into the `boot.img` and split the `ram-disk from it`. The OP can put the commands above in a script and download a third-party program to run it at boot. There are plenty of applications that have that capability and your solution is most likely too complex anyway.

Comment: What I have stated is a more permanent solution but worthwhile instead of relying on third-party apps. And also, init-scripts are where the permissions are set at boot prior to Android loading - Simples really, instead of resorting to fiddly hacks such as the above answer each time Android boots...

Comment: I know what you're talking about, but the solution proposed above is most likely a more viable solution for users in general, and probably for the OP as well. Your solution may be more permanent, but requires more knowledge of Android, `boot.img` splitting, and the Linux file system

Comment: You'd learn so much by doing that and makes you appreciate what Linux, Android has to offer :D

Comment: I know, but my answer was simply based on the fact that the majority of people who post on places like this are only looking for quick-and-dirty solutions...not mind-numbing learning processes, unfortunately :)

Comment: Ha! Fair enough then I suppose! :) Yeah, if everyone is enthusiastic about it... well that's what we're here for!!!! :D

Comment: Just thinking aloud: If the original permissions were `0666`, and you've changed them to `0777` -- all you did is make it *executable* for everybody (bit 1), as it before already was set read (bit 4) and write (2) for everybody. a) what should that achieve? and b) do you think it's really a good idea to keep it read- and writeable for every process? Original was rather `0644`, my guess ;)

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, I think in rwx type, but anyway you get the point

Comment: TBH, I agree with user999999999 in that I, as most users are, am only interested in a quick and dirty solution.  Running a script at boot time is actually not that dirty at all.